# Importing from directory in Windows

Tags: go

My `GOPATH` is `C:\src\go`, and I have a project which has the following directory structure:

```
C:\src\go\src\project\
                      main.go
                      folder\
                             file1.go
                             file2.go
                             file3.go
```

Where `file1.go, file2.go, file3.go` has one package name, and `main.go` has package name of main and the main method. In `main.go` I did something like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "./folder"
)
```

But then, I run from command line `go run main.go` and I get an error messages that the functions are undefined, because the package is not loaded correctly, in fact for the package load error I get:

```
.\main.go:5: imported and not used: "_/C_/src/go/src/project/folder"
```

where as can be seen the path is not quite correct. Any ideas how to do this import in Windows?

Comment: What is the package name of `file1`, `2` and `3`?

Comment: @Bassie their package name is bcns and my folder is also named bcns

Comment: Are you able to post the code? At leas the bit in `main.go` where you are now seeing the `imported and not used` error, and the definition of the function that fails

Comment: @Bassie Okay. I had forgot to make the function names uppercase in order to be exportable.

Comment: Nice, glad you found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the full import path from your go source folder so something like this :

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "project/folder"
)
```

I also highly recommend you restructure your GOPATH directory for organisation purposes so you can find importing your own projects much easier. https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/01.2.html

Comment: my bad, do not include the src in the path, just import "project/folder"